# Do I have to create my test database entries in each TestCase?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a ecommerce application where I have sub-applications such as `product`, `order`, `checkout` and so on. In each application I have a `tests.py` file containing test for that isolated part of the app.

Many of the different testcases/sub-apps use the same kind of data. For example, both product-tests, order-tests and checkout-tests need to have sample data for products, carts, currencies and so on.

Currently I'm creating this test data in the `setUp` function of each `TestCase`. But this means that I'm creating the same data over and over again, which seem very stupid and unnecessary.

Is there some way for me to create "global" test data for my test-database? That will be created first, before any TestCase is run? Or am I already doing the "correct" way, even though it seems bad?

I'm using Django, which is using the `unittest` python module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, a unit test should be as isolated from other unit-tests as possible.  Otherwise, changing the order in which the tests run could cause a previously passing test to fail (or visa-versa). So, I would recommend that you continue to set up and tear down the database before each test.  In my experience, you usually only need to set up a few items for each test -- And the same setup code can often be shared by multiple tests (e.g. by putting that code in a base-class's `setUp` method).

Of course, there are arguments for doing a setup ahead of time (for multiple tests) -- e.g. in a [`setUpClass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) method or even [`setUpModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule)...  The main argument is that it probably saves a little time when running the tests -- That's never been an issue for me as my tests have always been few enough to run in a second or two -- for me, Grokking the output takes significantly longer than running the test, so I've never worried about that too much.  The other advantage is that you could get a more "production-like" environment -- but generally, if your code is isolated enough to be easily unit-tested, that's probably not such a big deal.